# How to fetch only parts of json file in python3 requests module

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, google-classroom

So, I am writing a program in Python to fetch data from google classroom API using requests module. I am getting the full json response from the classroom as follows :

```
{'announcements': [{'courseId': '#############', 'id': '###########', 'text': 'This is a test','state': 'PUBLISHED', 'alternateLink': 'https://classroom.google.com/c/##########/p/###########', 'creationTime': '2021-04-11T10:25:54.135Z', 'updateTime': '2021-04-11T10:25:53.029Z', 'creatorUserId': '###############'}, {'courseId': '############', 'id': '#############', 'text': 'Hello everyone', 'state': 'PUBLISHED', 'alternateLink': 'https://classroom.google.com/c/#############/p/##################', 'creationTime': '2021-04-11T10:24:30.952Z', 'updateTime': '2021-04-11T10:24:48.880Z', 'creatorUserId': '##############'}, {'courseId': '##################', 'id': '############', 'text': 'Hello everyone', 'state': 'PUBLISHED', 'alternateLink': 'https://classroom.google.com/c/##############/p/################', 'creationTime': '2021-04-11T10:23:42.977Z', 'updateTime': '2021-04-11T10:23:42.920Z', 'creatorUserId': '##############'}]}
```

I was actually unable to convert this into a pretty format so just pasting it as I got it from the http request. What I actually wish to do is just request the first few announcements (say 1, 2, 3 whatever depending upon the requirement) from the service while what I'm getting are all the announcements (as in the sample 3 announcements) that had been made ever since the classroom was created. Now, I believe that fetching all the announcements might make the program slower and so I would prefer if I could get only the required ones. Is there any way to do this by passing some arguments or anything? There are a few direct functions provided by google classroom however I came across those a little later and have already written everything using the requests module which would require changing a lot of things which I would like to avoid. However if unavoidable I would go that route as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Use the `pageSize` field to limit the number of responses you want in the `announcements: list` request, with an `orderBy` parameter of `updateTime asc`.*

#### More Information:

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/list):

> `orderBy`: `string`
>
> Optional sort ordering for results. A comma-separated list of fields with an optional sort direction keyword. Supported field is `updateTime`. Supported direction keywords are `asc` and `desc`. If not specified, `updateTime desc` is the default behavior. Examples: `updateTime asc`, `updateTime`

and:

> `pageSize`: `integer`
>
> Maximum number of items to return. Zero or unspecified indicates that the server may assign a maximum.

So, let's say you want the first 3 announcements for a course, you would use a `pageSize` of `3`, and an `orderBy` of `updateTime asc`:

```py
# Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)

asc = "updateTime asc"
pageSize = 3

# Call the Classroom API
results = service.courses().announcements().list(pageSize=3, orderBy=asc ).execute()
```

or an HTTP request example:

```
GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/[COURSE_ID]/announcements
      ?orderBy=updateTime%20asc
      &pageSize=2
      &key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

#### References:

- [Method: announcements.list | Classroom API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/list)

Comment: This gave me the idea but did not give me the direct solution, but thanks. What I wanted was to use the requests library to send a GET request and not use the Google provided functions like build. You saying pageSize and orderBy acting as fields gave me the idea to try putting them as parameters and it worked. So thanks again!! cheers.